# Cannot Build Anroid Apk using Ionic CLI

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, environment-variables

[image: I am trying to build android apk using ionic cli]

I have build tools installed and are in path variable.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\ProgrammingSource\IonicProjects\ShoppingCartGeneric\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 68
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

Comment: what plugins are you using?

Comment: cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion" \n

cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device" \n

cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"

Answer (score 0):

using the following command i came to know that the build tools were not downloaded.

sdkmanager --list

Finally, this solved the problem..
sdkmanager "build-tools;19.1.0"